# Can I use .x as 0.x in CSS?

Tags: css

I found this CSS code working.

```
.xxx{
    opacity:.9;/*not 0.9*/
}
```

Can I use .x? Is it right syntax?I have googled. But I can't find information about this.Could you tell me if this is right syntax?

Comment: The right syntax for what?

Comment: `.9` is just an abbreviate way of writing `0.9`, you can also use this kind of shorthand in Javascript, also in another language like C#...

Comment: It's the right syntax if it works, otherwise it's not. But why do you care? Just write 0.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [CSS Level 3 Values and Units Spec, Section 4.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#numbers)

> **4.2. Numbers: the `‘<number>’` type**
>
> Number values are denoted by `<number>`. A number is either an `<integer>`
>   or **zero** or more **decimal digits followed by a dot (.)** followed by one
>   or more decimal digits. It corresponds to the NUMBER token in the
>   grammar. As with integers, the first character of a number may be
>   immediately preceded by ‘-’ or ‘+’ to indicate the number's sign.

[CSS 2,1, Section 4.3.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#numbers) uses the same wording.

Comment: I feel sorry because I cannot phrase my question in English well. But this answer tells me what I want to know. Thank you!